# Renew token does not work

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

If my connection app try to renew the token, it get an eror at class "OAuth2Handler" in method "protected AccessToken _renewToken(AccessToken token)"

```
{"error_description":"CWOAU0030E: An invalid HTTP method was used at the token endpoint: GET","error":"invalid_request"}
```

My token URL look good (?)

```
https://[server]/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/token
```

Have anybody an idea?

Comment: switch the http method to post

Comment: If the post is running the SBT SDK has a renew method which never will be work. :-(

Comment: did you setup your own token? in sbt.properties?

Comment: The customer token is configure and the access token is stored in my own cred store. The reload of the access token does work. Btw: The post does not worke too.

Comment: have you tried it in the REST Client from Firefox? what is returned?

Comment: Thx Paul. My mistake, the post does work now. I fixed the OAuth2handler.